# Drag Adorner on ListViewItem with a GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, adorner

I have a ListView containing objects and I have used a GridView to display the properties:

```
       <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fields}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="s_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="s_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" />
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="MouseMoveHandler" />                        
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >  
                    <GridViewColumn Header="1" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Textbox text={binding} />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn> 
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Then I have a drag and drop behavior set up on the ListView so that when an ListViewItem is dragged, I clone the controls template which becomes the drag adorner:

```
 private static ContentControl CreateClone(ListViewItem element)
 {
     ListViewItem control = new ListViewItem();
     if (element != null)
     {
         control.Content = element.Content;
         control.ContentTemplate = element.ContentTemplate;
         control.Template = element.Template;
         control.Style = element.Style;
         control.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
         control.Width = element.ActualWidth;
         control.Height = (element.ActualHeight);
         control.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
         control.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
         control.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
         control.Opacity = .70;
     }

     return control;
 }
```

My problem is that the ListViewItem does not have a ContenetTemplate, because im assuming it is defined by the GridView, So I end up with a blank adorner with no columns in it. Do I need to also define a template in the ItemContainerStyle?